# ¿Cómo validar dato NO numérico dentro de un bucle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Al entrarle un dato a esta función entra constantemente en el bucle y tampoco sale (por el `break` del `if`).

```
def comprobarEntero(entero):

    esEntero = isinstance(entero, int)

    while esEntero == False:
        print("ERROR. NO es un número entero...")
        entero = leerEntero()

        if esEntero:
            break

    return entero
```

Me gustaría en vez de usar una excepción poder arreglarlo, pedir un enunciado hasta que se introduzca correctamente el valor numérico.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda y el tiempo.

Comment: ¿Qué argumentos le estás pasando a la función? Por cierto, ¿qué hace `leerEntero()`?

Comment: Ahí esta el punto, hasta donde estoy viendo... leerEntero() solo tiene return input("Introduzca un numero ") por lo que intuyo que aun metiendo un entero se lía por el tratamiento del dato. De hecho si metes un 2, por ejemplo, la función isinstance() no trata al dato entero y da False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> al entrarle un dato a esta función entra constantemente en el bucle y tampoco sale

Esto pasa por que la continuación del bucle `while`, usa esta condición

```
isinstance(entero, int) == False
```

Siempre va a ser `False`, [`ininstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) valida si el primer argumento es instancia del segundo. En este caso el primero es tipo `str` y el segundo es `int`. Claramente nunca va a ser `True`.

> Me gustaría en vez de usar una excepción poder arreglarlo pidiendo enunciado hasta que se introduzca correctamente el valor numérico.

Puedes ayudarte de métodos que tienen los strings como [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) o [`isdecimal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str):

```
esEntero = entero.isdigit()

while not esEntero:
    ...
```

Saludos.

Comment: Correcto, ahora haciendo pruebas se soluciono fácilmente, como has comentado. def leerEntero():
 
 return input("Introduzca un número entero: ")


entero = leerEntero()
if (not entero.isdigit() or len(entero) != 1):

    esEntero = False

    while not esEntero:
        print("ERROR. No es un entero...")
        entero = leerEntero()

        if entero.isdigit() and len(entero) == 1:
            esEntero = True

print("Salio   ",entero)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que tu problema es simplemente que debes comprobar dentro del ciclo si es entero o no cada vez que el usuario ingresa algo, lo estas haciendo una únicamente antes de entrar al ciclo por lo que siempre va a ser false.

Por otra parte no necesitas un break, si tu condición principal en el ciclo es la misma que para el break.

Prueba con esto.

```
entero = leerEntero()
esEntero = isinstance(entero, int)
    
while not esEntero:
    print("ERROR. NO es un número entero...")
    entero = leerEntero()
    esEntero = isinstance(entero, int)

return entero
```

Espero se entienda lo que intente explicarte y te sea util.

Comment: Sii lo entiendo y es buena idea, pero **sigue fallando**...es lo que más a cuadros me deja, se carga toda lógica.

Comment: En ese caso te recomiendo colocar el def de leerEntero, podría estar ahí el problema.

Comment: Si sigue fallando luego de aplicar la idea de @JhoubertRincon con seguridad el problema está en la función leerEntero(). Posiblemente la validación deba hacerse allá usando algo como `entero = int(input('Ingrese un número entero'))` y validando allá mismo. Si la entrada genera error devuelve una señal "error" si es correcta devuelve el entero. Como la señal no es entero no pasa la validación y la lógica propuesta opera.